# Установка nuget пакета из локальной папки

Tags: c#

Как установить пакет с диска?

На самом сайте nuget его нету - ImageSharp.1.0.0-alpha9.nupkg это C# ImGUI

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally

Answer (score 2):

Вам когда-нибудь приходилось подключать сторонние репозитории?

Точно также подключите папку, в которой будут находится пакеты как отдельный репозиторий.

Для этого нужно зайти в **Tools - > Options -> Package Manager** (для студии с интерфейсом на английском языке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. по теме:

- [How to install a Nuget Package .nupkg file locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally)
- [MSDN. Hosting your own NuGet feeds](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/nuget/hosting-packages/overview)